# CakePHP: paginating, sorting, filtering data from cached tables

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, filter, pagination

I'm trying to use Cake's native caching methodes to cache some data that I will need to paginate, sort andfiler (search) - that's why I'm caching data arrays, not views or paginated arrays/views. As far as I can see searching/filtering components and Paginator only ask the database, which is what I don't want. Is there any way I could put these together in Cake? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're looking for some kind of array pagination?

Comment: Yes, sorry that it wasn't clear. And for filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct to assume that Cake always expects a database result to paginate. One of the easiest solutions is [refactoring a class like this one](http://lotsofcode.com/php/php-array-pagination.htm) into a helper (for the pagination) or a component (for filtering) and feed the helper/component your data arrays (more info on custom [helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1097/Creating-Helpers) and [components](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/996/Creating-Components)). The only downside to this is that your application has to read the cached arrays into memory before creating a paginated result set.

There's also [this article](http://www.jotlab.com/2010/02/09/pagination-caching-with-cakephp/), but I'm not sure if applies to your setup.

Another option might be to write your own datasource for cached data arrays, [but Cake's documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1076/Basic-API-For-DataSources) on this is a little meagre. I've dabbled in the creation of a datasource for some custom XML feeds, but never got around to adding pagination. From the third-party datasources floating around I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I did the first thing and the component seems to work. But it seems I'lll have to write sorting and filtering on my own, can't find anything for this.